# modules load Issue with upgrading to rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I got a new issue with module loading when upgraded an app from rails 4.2 to rails 5.1

Consider the following file tree

```
lib
-- core
------- util.rb
```

if util is a class defined like this

```
module Core 
  class Util 
  end
end
```

And I write

```
Core::Util.some_method
```

All good

If Util is a module

```
module Core 
  module Util 
  end
end
```

I get an error when trying to reference Core::Util, this didn't happen on rails 4.2.7.

the error I get is

> LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Core::Util expected /../lib/core/util.rb to define it.

Now if I change the folder structure and put another sub folder called util like this:

```
lib
- core
-- util
--- util.rb
```

the module Util works fine.

Is there a change in rails, do I need to do something ?

thanks,

Comment: Check here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25155#issuecomment-222100462, This might help.

Comment: @AtulKhanduri thanks, but this issue is relevant only for concerns, what about module used as namespace without any relation to concerns?